# CSS: Clear:left/right/both; VS Float: none;

Tags: css, css-float

I checked several questions on the matter both on the site and off but never have seem to have gotten a clear definition.

It seems through experimentation that `float: none;` removes the element from the float layout position altogether and places the element back into regular document flow.

`clear: left/right/both;` on the otherhand seems to break the floating of the element but **does not** place the element back into the regular document flow, rather keeping the element in the float layout position flow.

Is this a correct assumption and can this topic be explained more thoroughly or with a more credible source cited than individual experimentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clear`ing does not change the `float`ing status of an element - it merely defines whether the element is allowed to sit beside another or must wrap underneath.

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

---

**Here's an example of when you would need to `clear` an element:**
Note how it's the `footer` (a non-floating element) that needs the clearing applied in this case.

```css
section {float:left; width:60%; height:200px; background:rgba(255,0,0,.3);}
aside {float:right; width:40%; height:100px; background:rgba(0,255,0,.3);}
footer {/*clear:both;*/ background:rgba(0,0,255,.3);}
```

```html
<section>Main</section>
<aside>Sidebar</aside>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

---

**When Clearing is Not Enough...**

So, you've successfully floated your elements and have broken out of 'The Flow' but now you find yourself with a [zero-height/collapsing container problem](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)? For that you'll need a [clear-fix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). Here's an example of the problem and solution:

```css
section {border:1px solid red; padding:10px 5px; clear:both;}
span {display:block; float:left; width:80px; height:80px; margin:0 5px; background:rgba(100,100,100,.3)}

.clearfix {border-color:green;}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span>
</section>
<section class="clearfix">
    <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span>
</section>
```

Comment: While this certainly explains it more what about the clearfix technique? In this method for float layout design the class clearfix isn't floated but the addition of the clear declaration allows the block to act as a hybrid of sorts both aligning itself with the float flow layout and the regular document flow to make sure the non-floated parent doesn't collapse due to not seeing content.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Thanks for the feedback. Although the clearfix technique was not part of the OP's question I agree that is it worth a mention here.